# vanilla php convert base64 to image in email attachment

Tags: php, base64

I have a php script that sends me an email. Within this email data, I send base64 image data, but what I would like is that the base64 gets converted into a `jpeg` which then gets added as an attachment via email.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $to      = 'my@email.com';
    $subject = "New submission from ".$_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $image = base64_to_jpeg( $_POST['image'], 'image.jpeg' ); //this is base64 image
    $subscribe = $_POST['subscribe'];
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']." <".">\r\n"; $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    if(mail($to, $subject, $image, $headers)) echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);
    else echo json_encode(['success'=>false]);
    exit;
 }

function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    // open the output file for writing
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' );

    // split the string on commas
    // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
    // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );

    // we could add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );

    // clean up the file resource
    fclose( $ifp );

    return $output_file;
}
?>
```

`$image` is `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg`

The issue I'm having is that when the email gets sent, the email only inclues plain text "image.jpeg" rather than showing the image, or attaching the image...

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `$image` to the body of the mail would obviously send the name, because that's what you're returning from the function.

But if you pass it with an image tag;

```
mail($to, $subject, '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="'. $image . '">', $headers); // I used PHP template strings to create the img tag
```

You're surely going to get the data string passed into the mail's body

Here's a screenshot with the link you posted me
[image: Screenshot of the final image]

This is the complete code I'm running `base64_to_jpeg` is your function I got from the question

```
<?php

function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file)
{
    // open the output file for writing
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, 'wb');

    // split the string on commas
    // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
    // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

    // we could add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1]));

    // clean up the file resource
    fclose($ifp);

    return $output_file;
}

    $image = base64_to_jpeg(base64_string_from_link, 'image.jpeg')
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Base 64</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $image . '">'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand your problem now, When you pass the `$image` to the mail's body, the `alt` text is showing simply because, the mail doesn't know where to download the image from.

When you're sending images through mail, the image links have to be absolute paths for the mail to know where to download the image from.

Therefore, either you upload that image to your websites file manager and use an absolute path like so, `<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">`

or

don't convert the image to `.jpeg`, just pass the `base 64` string as the image's src `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg">`

I also saw in your code that you're not concatenating the `$headers` together rather just resetting the value. (i.e. you're using `=` instead of `.=`)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I have tried what you suggested but it appears as a broken image.. the image src seems to be pointing to `http://doodle.jpeg`.. any idea why?

Comment: Then it must be what is returned from your function as the image name. I tried it on my system with your function and my code. And when I removed the `img` tag, I got the name of the image. When i didn't remove it, I got the image I converted to the `base 64` string

Comment: Can you show an screenshot of the image you’re trying to convert and the way it shows on your browser?

Comment: I added the base64 to the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/tPnVgwzY, it just shows the default icon when an image src is not correct.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot

Comment: Okay it might work in a localhost environment, but in an email environment (I'm sending an email to my gmail account, the image is empty..)

Comment: @Simon please look at the edited part of my code, I think that should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, I ended up storing the file on my server and referencing it in the `src` rather than base64 because it seems Gmail doesn't support base64 images.